# How do I load PHP include conditionally?

Tags: php

I have a page that displays an include depending on language selected. It works perfectly in Classic ASP, but I have converted to PHP and it is ignoring the IF condition completely. For example:

```
if ($Lang = "AR") {
    include 'inc_default_ar.php';
} elseif ($Lang = "CN") {
    include 'inc_default_cn.php';
} elseif ($Lang = "CS") {
    include 'inc_default_cs.php';
} else {
    include 'inc_default_en.php';
}
```

Even though `$Lang = "EN"` it somehow displays the AR include, even though it is not a match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use == to check for equality.

```
if ($Lang == "AR") {
    include 'inc_default_ar.php';
} elseif ($Lang == "CN") {
    include 'inc_default_cn.php';
} elseif ($Lang == "CS") {
    include 'inc_default_cs.php';
} else {
    include 'inc_default_en.php';
}
```

Comment: This worked. I''l run with this because my code needs the "else" fallback.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @pew007's answer. But if you change up your code a little bit and always have the $Lang variable set you could do something like the following.

```
include "inc_default_".strtolower($Lang).".php"
```

Comment: I think ``strtolower($Lang)`` might be the more appropriate choice given OP's code.

Comment: $Lang and $LangCode (ie: "_en" are available)

Comment: This worked when I corrected your typo :-)

Comment: Oops wrong function. I've updated my answer, thanks @kmoser